# Two left joins and records from the last hour

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT p.*, 
       u.user_id, 
       u.user_name, 
       count(c.comment_post_id) AS comments, 
       c.comment_added 
    FROM posts as p 
        LEFT JOIN comments as c 
            ON (p.post_id=c.comment_post_id) 
        LEFT JOIN users as u 
            ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id) 
    GROUP BY p.post_id 
    HAVING c.comment_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
    ORDER BY comments DESC
```

I'm not very good at mysql, but after a little research I managed to write this.

What's supposed to happen here is a list of posts, ordered by whichever has the most comments within the last hour. My noobscript should be able to explain the important parts of the DB structure. Some of the SELECTed items is for php purposes.

What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your Posts->Comments is a 1:Many relationship, you can't have a field from `comments` in your result set and expect to group by `posts`. Remove `c.comment_added` and I think you'll get the results you expect.

Furthermore move your `HAVING` stuff into a `WHERE` clause. `HAVING` is determined after aggregation, but you don't want `comments_added` to be in your aggregation for the reason stated above. More properly, you want to filter the `comments` table before aggregations which is what the `WHERE` will do.

```
SELECT p.*,
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    count(c.comment_post_id) AS comments
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN comments AS c
    ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id)
LEFT JOIN users AS u
    ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id)
WHERE c.comment_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
GROUP BY p.post_id    
ORDER BY count(c.comment_post_id)  DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining! This will help me accomplish another thing too I have planned. Your script worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The code won't run because you have a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, but you have more columns in your `SELECT` than you have in the `GROUP BY` (you should have the same non-aggregated columns (i.e. columns not used in Sum, Min, Max, Count, Avg, etc) in both places.

Also, you can't (and shouldn't) use P.* in your `SELECT`.  I have added a couple of dummy column names (which, you should replace with actual column names).

Lastly, if you expect to count the number of comments, then you shouldn't have the `c.comment_added` timestamp in your `SELECT`.

The SQL below will give you all posts within the last hour ordered by the number of comments they have

```
SELECT p.COL1, P.COl2, u.user_id, u.user_name, count(c.comment_post_id) AS comments
FROM posts as p 
LEFT JOIN comments as c 
    ON (p.post_id=c.comment_post_id) 
LEFT JOIN users as u 
    ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id) 
Where c.comment_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
Group By p.COL1, P.COl2, u.user_id, u.user_name
Order By count(c.comment_post_id) Desc
```